# How to import svg file, alter it, and export it again?

Tags: r, svg

In my workflow I want to be able to import a svg-file into r, change the width and height, and export it again. Does anyone know a package that can do that? I tried `xml` packages together with the `svg()` function, but there was no success. I want to change the width from 720px to 800px and the heigth from 150px to 200px.

This is a part of the svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="720px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 720 150" version="1.1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
library(XML)
svg <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="75.405006"
   height="75.405006"
   id="svg11758">
  <defs
     id="defs11760" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata11763">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(-322.56587,-311.71745)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="m 397.97087,349.41995 a 37.702503,37.702503 0 1 1 -75.405,0 37.702503,37.702503 0 1 1 75.405,0 z"
       id="path11770"
       style="color:#000000;fill:#008080;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;marker:none;visibility:visible;display:inline;overflow:visible;enable-background:accumulate" />
  </g>
</svg>'
xml <- xmlParse(svg, asText = TRUE)
d <- xmlRoot(xml)
xmlAttrs(d) <- setNames(as.numeric(xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(xml))[c("width", "height")]) * 2, c("width", "height"))
saveXML(xml, file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xml"))
```

This resizes the canvas.

Comment: Thanks! does it save the file as an .svg file again? And how to import the svg file in the first place?

Comment: (1) Yes, enter `cat(tf)` to view the filename. (2) Use `xml <- xmlParse(MySvgFileName)` to import.

Comment: so, if i have a file somewhere, like /route/myfile.svg, I only have to do this: xml <- xmlParse("/route/myfile.svg")?

Comment: Yes, if /route/myfile.svg is the path from your current R working directory.

Comment: The reason I asked is because I keep on getting this error: Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:

Comment: removing 'asText = TRUE' solves it, so it seems. Now I have another question. xmlAtrrs part gives this error: Warning message:
In setNames(as.numeric(xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(xml))[c("width", "height")]) *  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Maybe there are no height, width attributes? I don't know because I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: `setNames(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(xml))[c("width", "height")])) * 2, c("width", "height"))`?